# How to function data in foreach returned from another function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to use foreach on data that is returned from my another function: 
I am using below:

```
function getAllCompetitors() {
    console.log('In getAllCompetitors function js file');
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/salescrm/getAllCompetitors',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('getAllCompetitors data: ',data);
            //response(data);
            return data;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('data error: ',error);
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my foreach:

```
getAllCompetitors.foreach(function(item){

})
```

Its showing error.

I want, to use foreach on data that is returned from function.
Can anybody assist me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getAllCompetitors()` returns the ajax call, *not* the data from the success handler.  If you want to parse the data then you do it either inside the success handler, or you call another function from there and pass the data as a parameter.

Comment: ^^ ...or use the fact that the `jqXHR` object is Promise-like (and Promise-compatible in modern versions of jQuery) and use `then`/`catch` on it (or even `async`/`await` in cutting-edge environments or via transpilation). Also note that JavaScript is case-sensitive, `foreach` != `forEach`.